# Check if url exists or not using PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

currently i am using following function

```
function urlExist($url)
{
                $handle   = curl_init($url);
                if (false === $handle)
                {
                        return false;
                }
                curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
                curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);  // this works
                curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.15) Gecko/20080623 Firefox/2.0.0.15") ); // request as if Firefox
                curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
                curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
                $connectable = curl_exec($handle);
                ##print $connectable;
                curl_close($handle);
                return $connectable;
}
```

It works fine for simple url but does not work for url that redirects to another domain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set`FOLLOWLOCATION`:

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

*However*, there is no point in issuing a GET request here. A simple HEAD is lighter since only headers are transferred. To do that, set `NOBODY` to true:

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same function but i'm not meeting problem with domain trieuvieclam.com redirect to new domain. I'm using CHROME browser

```
function url_exists($url) {
    $handle   = curl_init($url);
    if (false === $handle)
    {
            return false;
    }

    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);  // this works
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.15) Gecko/20080623 Firefox/2.0.0.15") ); // request as if Firefox
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3);
    $connectable = curl_exec($handle);
    ##print $connectable;
    curl_close($handle);
    if($connectable){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have tried change this line :`curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` to `false`, but the result is still the same (existing the domain).

```
if (false === $handle)
        {
                return false;
        }
```

This condition never meet for any string, even not an url, maybe it only match when curl is not supported in the server.